# 2.6.38-10 stops booting

Tags: 11.04, boot, kernel, grub2

11.04 natty narwhale (2.6.38-10) stop boot.

After work with: gparted, palimpsest, mountmanager.
sda:

```
sda1 ntfs flag: boot  Windows 7  mbr
sda2 ntfs
sda3 extended flag: lba (?)
sda5 ntfs
sda6 ext4  Ubuntu 11.04
sda4 ext4
```

stops after:

```
uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: Unlink after no-IRQ? Controller is probably using the wrong IRQ
```

another time (after edit in Grub 1.98 with "c" or "e"):

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
```

or

```
usbhid: USB HID core driver
init: plymouth main process (256) terminated with status 1
init: plymouth-splash main process (885) terminated with status 2
```

or

```
ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 Scontrol 300)
ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 Scontrol 300)
```

How can I boot it? Thank You.

- I can boot to windows. I already tried unplug every devices except keyboard ps2, sda with system and monitor dvi. Bios is the newest one for this motherboard.

Comment: Can you boot to windows? If yes Then unplug any Usb devices and try to boot. If no look for a bios update and Then unplug any Usb devices. Sometimes a device can flake out the motherboard and cuase the system not to boot properly.

Comment: Yes, I can boot to windows.
I already tried unplug every devices except keyboard ps2, sda with system and monitor dvi.
Bios is the newest one for this motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I set up fresh ubuntu 11.04 natty narwhale on sdb1,
but grub 1.99 still doesn't boot - I have to do it in command line.
I repaired this by installing boot-repair:
([instructions in Polish](http://www.ubucentrum.net/2011/07/boot-repair-naprawa-bootloadera-kilkoma.html)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```